# Mysterious (I think) buffer over run in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, buffer, buffer-overrun

Sorry if this is a duplicate post.
I am currently having an issue where I am getting a warning on this piece of code saying `C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'titleTextPointer'` but I'm fairly sure that there would be no buffer over runs (this is assuming that all titles end with `'\0'`):

```c
    const char *title = "test";
    int titleLen = 0;
    while (title[titleLen] != '\0') {
        titleLen++;
    }
    WCHAR *titleTextPointer = (WCHAR *)malloc(sizeof(WCHAR) * (titleLen + 1)); //creates a new wide char list(WCHAR array) +1 for a terminating character(\0)
    if (titleTextPointer == NULL) {
        printf("error occured while locating space\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < titleLen; i++) { //iterates through lists and transfers memory
        titleTextPointer[i] = title[i]; //actual transfer (char is 1byte, wide char is 2 bytes)
    }
    titleTextPointer[titleLen] = '\0'; //adds the last terminating value to properly use the widechar in function
```

[code with error attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDwcr.png)

I've tried allocating more space (+2) but the warning still pops up.

Comment: What's the value of i when it fail?

Comment: `int titleLen = strlen(title);` Don't reinvent the wheel. Also `const char[] title = "test";` And if you iterate until `i <= titleLen` you will copy the trailing null automatically.

Comment: It's important to know that Intellisense isn't perfect.

Comment: 1) Post compliable code including the `#includes` used.  [mcve].  2) Use `size_t titleLen;`.

Comment: @user207421, No, `const char* title = "test"` makes more sense than `const char[] title = "test";`.

Comment: `titleTextPointer[i] = title[i];` is not a correct way to convert from "ANSI" to Wide.

Comment: The code is impossible to read with that single line `printf(); return 1;` and comments all over the place.  "actual transfer" doesn't make sense to me your source array contains 1 byte elements and your target 2 byte so two bytes are copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted does not exhibit any buffer overrun so I submit that your IDE is hallucinating.  I don't know what `WCHAR` is so used `wchar_t` which is 4 bytes on my system.  Note @ikegami's point that straight assignment might not be a correct mapping from `char *` to `wchat_t *`.  Here is a minimal (non-reproducible) example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *title = "test";
    size_t titleLen = strlen(title);
    wchar_t *titleTextPointer = malloc(sizeof *titleTextPointer * (titleLen + 1));
    if (!titleTextPointer) {
        printf("error occurred while locating space\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= titleLen; i++)
        titleTextPointer[i] = (unsigned char) title[i];
    free(titleTextPointer);
}
```

Comment: Also suggest this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205179/vs2015-c6386-buffer-overrun-while-writing-even-for-same-index-value